# Create instance inside abstract class of child using this

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an abstract class that does `new this()`, however, it isn't creating an instance of itself, but it is creating an instance of the class that extended it.

This works in JavaScript when compiled and returns the proper class. However, TypeScript is complaining.

> Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

```
abstract class Model {
  static find<T extends Model>(someVar) {
    let inst = new this() as T
    // Do some extra stuff with the instance
    return inst
  }
}

class A extends Model { }

A.find()
```

Comment: Looks like instead of using `new this()` I need to use `Reflect.construct(this, [])`

Answer (score 0):

The first problem of your solution - it isn't safe, `T` type may not contain empty constructor. The second problem: even if you call `find()` on `A` class, return type will be inferred as `Model` if it isn't set explicitly.

Because anyway you should specify A type when you call `find`, it would be better to pass the type constructor to the find method, in this case both problems will be solved.

```js
abstract class Model {
  static find<T extends Model>(ModelClass: new () => T, param: string): T {
    let inst = new ModelClass()
    // Do some extra stuff with the instance
    return inst;
  }
}

class A extends Model {}
const a = Model.find(A, "param");
```